# Error trying to connect to my Mongo database (MongooseServerSelectionError)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem with my code. I am attempting to connect to my MongoDB database, but I am encountering an issue, and I'm unsure of the root cause. I have already reviewed similar questions on Stack Overflow related to this problem, but none of them seem to provide a solution. Below is the error message I'm encountering:

```
An error has occurred while connecting to the database: MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 5000 ms
```

I am running MongoDB as a service, and I connect to it using MongoDB Compass. Additionally, I have tried connecting using the MongoDB shell, and I can see the database, create collections, but the backend of my application is unable to establish a connection to the database.

Here is the connection string I am using:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/dev
```

I have also tried using the IP address instead of 'localhost,' but I encounter the same error. I'm uncertain whether the issue lies within my code or MongoDB itself. I have even uninstalled and reinstalled MongoDB, but the problem persists

This is the full error message:

```
An error has occurred while connecting to the database: MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 5000 ms
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: you should provide the full error message

Comment: added the full error message

Comment: try setting bigger server selection timeout, but mostlikely the server is not accessible

Comment: try connection via mongo shell to ensure

Comment: I tryed with mongo shell. The dev database was created using shell, but now I cannot connect with that db

Comment: @dododo thanks bro, I love you. The problem was de server selection timeout

Comment: 5 seconds should be enough to be honest to select server for most of the cases, it's bit strange that it didn't work for you

Comment: @dododo yes, I think that, but it's the only way to work on my laptop